# Java app to run its own JVM on mac and windows

Tags: java, jvm, install4j

we currently have a java application packed with its own JVM. We wanted that so we don't have surprises with the different JRE versions out there. This app now needs to be runnable on mac so i need a config file somewhere that tells the java app to open a different JVM based on the operating system. Where can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: we need a little more details on how you start the app.

Comment: If your application belongs to a company who can afford a code signing certificate, Java Web Start is a perfect solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you put the `install4j` tag on your question, I'll add the perspective from install4j's side:

In install4j, you can bundle a JRE with your application, so that only the bundled JRE will be used. You can do that on the "Bundled JREs" step of the media wizard.